# Error while uploading file in PHP

Tags: php

While uploading the file in php i am not able to upload all types of file, if any space is there in between file name that is not able to download. Please can anyone correct this code

here is my upload code

```
<?php

$target_path = "../mt/sites/default/files/ourfiles/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}



$con = mysql_connect("localhost","mt","mt");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }else{
 echo "Connected";
}

// Create table
mysql_select_db("mt", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mt_upload (FileName, FilePath)
VALUES ('".basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])."', '".$target_path.basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])."')");


// Execute query
mysql_query($sql,$con);

mysql_close($con);



?>
```

Comment: Rename the title to 'PHP Upload filename with spaces problem*. And put the description in the question.

Answer (score 1):

make some check and validation on the file u upload

the script below can help u :

```
//  5MB maximum file size 
$MAXIMUM_FILESIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024; 
//  Valid file extensions (images, word, excel, powerpoint) 
$rEFileTypes = 
  "/^\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|doc|docx|txt|rtf|pdf|xls|xlsx| 
        ppt|pptx){1}$/i"; 
$dir_base = "/your/file/location/"; 

$isFile = is_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']); 
if ($isFile)    //  do we have a file? 
   {//  sanatize file name 
    //     - remove extra spaces/convert to _, 
    //     - remove non 0-9a-Z._- characters, 
    //     - remove leading/trailing spaces 
    //  check if under 5MB, 
    //  check file extension for legal file types 
    $safe_filename = preg_replace( 
                     array("/\s+/", "/[^-\.\w]+/"), 
                     array("_", ""), 
                     trim($_FILES['Filedata']['name'])); 
    if ($_FILES['Filedata']['size'] <= $MAXIMUM_FILESIZE && 
        preg_match($rEFileTypes, strrchr($safe_filename, '.'))) 
      {$isMove = move_uploaded_file ( 
                 $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], 
                 $dir_base.$safe_filename);} 
      } 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works, but try to change line 2 to this:

```
$target_path = $target_path . basename( urldecode ( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] ) );
```